# Number of possible values of $a,b,c$ such that the expression is divisible by $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a,b,c$ belongs to natural numbers less than equal to $p$ , where $p$ is an odd prime . 
Find the number of solutions of $a,b,c$ such that $a^2-bc$ is divisible by $p$.

Answer in terms of $p$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the special cases where one or both of $b$ and $c$ is equal to $p$. Then $a$ must be $p$. There are $2p-1$ ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ of this type.

Now consider the cases where neither $b$ nor $c$ is divisible by $p$.  There are $p-1$ possibilities for $b$. Fix one of these.

If $b$ is a quadratic residue of $p$, then any of the $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues of $p$ will work for $c$.

If $b$ is a quadratic non-residue of $p$, then any quadratic non-residue of $p$ will work for $c$.

Thus for any $b$ between $1$ and $p-1$, there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ choices for $c$. Finally, for any $r$ which is a quadratic residue of $p$, there are $2$ solutions of $a^2\equiv r\pmod{p}$. It follows that the number of triples where neither $b$ nor $c$ is divisible by $p$ is $(p-1)\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)(2)$, which is $(p-1)^2$.

Add the $2p-1$ that we got earlier, and we end up with $p^2$, a simple answer for which there is undoubtedly a simple solution.